# Mongoose query returning in Node/Express CRUD API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

It works fine for most cases of the this admin.js routing, however the .get() request near bottom for the .put() and delete() requests renders properly and the data is visible on the page, however in my terminal receive this error

> ... /admin.js:91
>               res.render('admin', {title: post.title, body: post.body});
>                                               ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

When attempting to edit or delete the post that is rendered on the form, I receive a 'This wepage is not visible' error. So it renders well and then crashes.

Here is the admin.js routing.  Is it possibly an issue of ordering?  I can't see why this would crash.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var session = require('client-sessions');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('users');
var Post = mongoose.model('posts');
var Song = mongoose.model('songs');
var Project = mongoose.model('projects');

// check whether User is logged in
function requireLogin(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
        req.session.reset();
        res.redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        next();
    }
};

router
    // Register
    .get('/register', requireLogin, function(req, res) {
        res.render('register');
    })

    .post('/register', function(req, res) {
        new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            password: req.body.password
        })
        .save(function(err, user) {
            res.redirect('/admin');
        });
    })

    // Login
    .get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('login');
    })

    .post('/', function(req, res) {
        User.findOne({name: req.body.name}, function(err, user) {
            if (!user) {
                res.render('login', {error: 'User not found'});
            } else if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
                req.session.user = user;
                res.redirect('/admin/dashboard');
            } else {
                res.render('login', {error: 'Incorrect Password'});
            }
        });
    })  

    // Admin dashboard
    .get('/dashboard', requireLogin, function(req, res) {
        res.render('admin');
    })

    .post('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
        // Depending on which form was filled, create new entry and redirect
        if (req.body.postTitle) {
            new Post({title: req.body.postTitle, body: req.body.body})
            .save(function(err, post) {
                res.redirect('/posts');
            });
        } else if (req.body.songTitle) {
            new Song({title: req.body.songTitle, arist: req.body.artist, link: req.body.link})
            .save(function(err, song) {
                res.redirect('/music');
            });
        } else if (req.body.projectName) {
            new Project({
                name: req.body.projectName,
                picture: req.body.picture,
                languages: req.body.languages,
                summary: req.body.summary
            })
            .save(function(err, project) {
                res.redirect('/projects');
            });
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    })

    .get('/dashboard/:title_slug', function(req, res) {
        var query = {'title_slug': req.params.title_slug};
        Post.findOne(query, function(err, post) {
            res.render('admin', {title: post.title, body: post.body});
        });
    })

    .put('/dashboard/:title_slug', function(req, res) {
        var query = {'title_slug': req.params.title_slug};
        var update = {'title': req.params.title, 'body': req.params.body};
        var options = {new: true};
        Post.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, post) {
            res.render('admin', 
                {
                    title: post.title,
                    body: post.body
                }
            );
        });
    })

    .delete('/dashboard/:title_slug', function(req, res) {
        var query = {'title_slug': req.params.title_slug};
        Post.findOneAndRemove(query, function(err, post) {
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    })

    // Logout
    .get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.session.reset();
        res.redirect('/admin');
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Example of form for DELETE request in admin.html

```
<div class='form posts-form'>
    <h2>Posts</h2>
    <form method='post' id='post' action'/admin/dashboard/{{post.title_slug}}?_method=DELETE'>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type='text' name='postTitle' value='{{title}}'></br>
        <label>Body</label>
        <textarea name='body' form='post'>{{body}}</textarea></br>
        <button type='submit'>Delete</button>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also check for if(!post){ console.log("no post found")}. Because it looks like there is no item found and you are trying to get title on a not founded object.

```
Post.findOne(query, function(err, post) {
    if (err)
       console.log(err);
    if (!post)
       console.log("not found")
    else
       res.render('admin', {title: post.title, body: post.body});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Strange, including if (!post) does not output any error, however the previous Type Error has now disappeared.  So while although functionally nothing has changed, and there aren't any new error messages, the original error message is now gone.

Comment: but "not found" is printed by the console? looks like now you are not entering the else case so the error is not thrown

Comment: Restarted nodemon and now 'not found' is indeed being thrown even though the post is being correctly rendered in the form for editing and deletion.  It is somehow finding the post to render but still not finding it.  Strange

Comment: Did you check your req.params.title_slug maybe it is not right try a consol.log(req.params.title_slug)

Comment: Yeah the title slug is correct, it is retrieving the post just fine to populate the form data with.

Comment: Ok so the problem is not in the get it is in delete / put hm did you tried to use findOne in delete / put and do the logic manually i hope you understand what i mean?

Comment: Tried manual logic for the put method.  Also tried variations of only including  put/delete methods and regardless what changes I receive a 404 for POST request to ~dashboard/title_slug.

Comment: Got it:  First as show in the view above, at some point in my debugging had changed the form action to be without '='.  Next I separated the model logic and added error handling throughout every step.  Learning TDD will be my next goal to bypass a lot of these issues.  Thank you for the responses.  Since error handling and your responses did help in the process will upvote/check.